# How can I recover files from partitioned disk?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, windows

I have a Windows machine in which I had my data files. I have partitioned the drive to install Ubuntu and accidentally installed Ubuntu in the drive where I had all my important files. How can I recover those files now?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu into the partition, where Windows was installed, and where you had your data files? Have you got a backup of the most important files? -- If not, some of the files might be overwritten, but Ubuntu is small, and probably most of the file data are located in other parts of the partition, and can be recovered. If nothing else works, use PhotoRec, http://cgsecurity.org , but it is a lot of work. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986, scroll down to 'Advanced repair of a partition table, file system and/or recovery of files'.

Comment: I was able to find the files in ubuntu. The list of my files were initially `myfile1.fast5`, `myfile2.fast5`. Now they are `myfile1.mpeg`, `myfile2.mpeg` and the file size is reduced significantly for each file. Is there a way I can revert them back to the original file format?

Comment: Were the files found as normal files in Ubuntu? Or did you use a recovery tool to find them? Do you know why they have the extension mpeg (have you converted them earlier, or did a recovery tool guess, that the extension should be mpeg)?

Comment: Yes it was recovered and the tool changed them to mpeg extension.

Comment: Well, you could simply change the extension to what it was before. I would think that the content is the same. But it makes me worried, that the size is smaller. Maybe they were fragmented, and the recovery tool did not find all fragments. -- Try to play the files with your favourite multimedia player. (You can try with both extensions.)